# I can't upload image from admin in magento 1.9 its giving some html in response

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento-1.9

I have error to upload file in magento for product image
When click on upload its given error in file upload and I checked in product.js for item response, here its coming html instead of json

Like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Log into Magento Admin Page</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/projects/vpower/skin/adminhtml/default/default/reset.css" media="all" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/projects/vpower/skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="icon" href="http://localhost/projects/vpower/skin/adminhtml/default/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/projects/vpower/skin/adminhtml/default/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/projects/vpower/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/projects/vpower/js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/projects/vpower/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/projects/vpower/js/mage/adminhtml/form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/projects/vpower/js/mage/captcha.js"></script>

    <!--[if IE]> <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/projects/vpower/skin/adminhtml/default/default/iestyles.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 7]> <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/projects/vpower/skin/adminhtml/default/default/below_ie7.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]> <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/projects/vpower/skin/adminhtml/default/default/ie7.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> <![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="page-login" onload="document.forms.loginForm.username.focus();">
    <div class="login-container">
        <div class="login-box">
            <form method="post" action="" id="loginForm" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="login-form">
                    <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="BuvGes0fQKBEduj2" />
                    <h2>Log in to Admin Panel</h2>
                    <div id="messages">
                                            </div>
                    <div class="input-box input-left"><label for="username">User Name:</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="login[username]" value="" class="required-entry input-text" /></div>
                    <div class="input-box input-right"><label for="login">Password:</label><br />
                        <!-- This is a dummy hidden field to trick firefox from auto filling the password -->
                        <input type="text" class="input-text no-display" name="dummy" id="dummy" />
                        <input type="password" id="login" name="login[password]" class="required-entry input-text" value="" /></div>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="form-buttons">
                        <a class="left" href="http://localhost/projects/vpower/index.php/adam_admin2016/index/forgotpassword/">Forgot your password?</a>
                        <input type="submit" class="form-button" value="Login" title="Login" /></div>
                </div>
<!--                <p class="legal">Magento is a trademark of Magento Inc. Copyright &copy; 2018 Magento Inc.</p>-->
            </form>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                 var loginForm = new varienForm('loginForm');
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but it should be like

```
{"name":"bosch.jpg","type":"application/octet-stream","tmp_name":"C:/wamp64/tmp/phpA041.tmp","error":0,"size":7776,"path":"C:/wamp64/www/magento19/media/tmp/catalog/product","file":"/b/o/bosch_4.jpg.tmp","url":"http://localhost/magento19/media/tmp/catalog/product/b/o/bosch_4.jpg","cookie":{"name":"adminhtml","value":"gefbr1inal64iobpi30rmuc2n1","lifetime":"3600","path":"/magento19","domain":"localhost"}}
```

Comment: I already added the permission 777 to media folder

Comment: The content of the title element should be your first indicator where to look ...

Answer (score -1):

When you click on the Upload file button at that time admin session expired and that is why return the admin login HTML.

So, resolve the admin logout issues and your image upload properly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30087077)